# TableView cell For Row At function says Index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an 2 arrays. 1 of these arrays includes city names. The other array includes university name arrays like [[String]]. I want to create a tableView. I wonder there are sections named cities and rows under sections which named university names. But when I run my app the error occurs and it says "Index out of range". Where is my fault?

Here is my ViewModel file:

```
struct ProvinceListViewModel {
    //Fetch provinces as an array
    func getProvinces(completion: @escaping([String]) -> ()){
        var list = [Province]()
        var resultList = [String]()
        APIService().callApi { dataList in
            guard let dataList = dataList else {return}
            list = dataList
            print(list[1].province)
            for i in dataList {
                resultList.append(i.province)
                //print(resultList)   
            }
            completion(resultList)
        }
    }
}

struct UniversityListViewModel {
    func getUniversities(completion : @escaping([[String]])-> ()) {
        //var provinceList = [Province]()
        APIService().callApi { provinces in
            guard let provinces = provinces else {return}
            //provinceList = provinces
            var uninameList = [String]()
            var uniNameArray = [[String]]()
            for province in provinces {
                uninameList.removeAll()
                for i in province.universities {
                    uninameList.append(i.name)
                }
                uniNameArray.append(uninameList)
            }
            completion(uniNameArray)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my View File :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var listViewModel = ProvinceListViewModel()
    var uniViewModel = UniversityListViewModel()
    var uniList = [[String]]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                //print(self.uniList)
            }
        }
    }
    var provincelist = [String]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.provincelist)
            }
        }
    }
   
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        listViewModel.getProvinces { provinces in
            self.provincelist = provinces
            print(provinces[0])
        }
        uniViewModel.getUniversities { unis in
            self.uniList = unis
        }  
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return provincelist.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return provincelist[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = uniList[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int      {
        return uniList[section].count
    }
}
```

I want to show you my arrays. I printed them before running the app to test my arrays but I couldn't find any problem in arrays.

Here is my ProvinceList Array:

```
["ADANA", "ADIYAMAN", "AFYONKARAHİSAR", "AĞRI", "AMASYA", "ANKARA", "ANTALYA", "ARTVİN", "AYDIN", "BALIKESİR", "BİLECİK", "BİNGÖL", "BİTLİS", "BOLU", "BURDUR", "BURSA", "ÇANAKKALE", "ÇANKIRI", "ÇORUM", "DENİZLİ", "DİYARBAKIR", "EDİRNE", "ELAZIĞ", "ERZİNCAN", "ERZURUM", "ESKİŞEHİR", "GAZİANTEP", "GİRESUN", "GÜMÜŞHANE", "HAKKARİ", "HATAY", "ISPARTA", "MERSİN", "İSTANBUL", "İZMİR", "KARS", "KASTAMONU", "KAYSERİ", "KIRKLARELİ", "KIRŞEHİR", "KOCAELİ", "KONYA", "KÜTAHYA", "MALATYA", "MANİSA", "KAHRAMANMARAŞ", "MARDİN", "MUĞLA", "MUŞ", "NEVŞEHİR", "NİĞDE", "ORDU", "RİZE", "SAKARYA", "SAMSUN", "SİİRT", "SİNOP", "SİVAS", "TEKİRDAĞ", "TOKAT", "TRABZON", "TUNCELİ", "ŞANLIURFA", "UŞAK", "VAN", "YOZGAT", "ZONGULDAK", "AKSARAY", "BAYBURT", "KARAMAN", "KIRIKKALE", "BATMAN", "ŞIRNAK", "BARTIN", "ARDAHAN", "IĞDIR", "YALOVA", "KARABÜK", "KİLİS", "OSMANİYE", "DÜZCE"]
```

Here is my uniList:

```
[["ADANA BİLİM VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ÇUKUROVA ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ADIYAMAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["AFYON KOCATEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "AFYONKARAHİSAR SAĞLIK BİLİMLERİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["AĞRI İBRAHİM ÇEÇEN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["AMASYA ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ANKA TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANKARA HACI BAYRAM VELİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANKARA MEDİPOL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANKARA MÜZİK VE GÜZEL SANATLAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANKARA SOSYAL BİLİMLER ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANKARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANKARA YILDIRIM BEYAZIT ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ATILIM ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BAŞKENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ÇANKAYA ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "GAZİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "HACETTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İHSAN DOĞRAMACI BİLKENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "LOKMAN HEKİM ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ORTA DOĞU TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "OSTİM TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TED ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TOBB EKONOMİ VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TÜRK HAVA KURUMU ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "UFUK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "YÜKSEK İHTİSAS ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["AKDENİZ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ALANYA ALAADDİN KEYKUBAT ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ALANYA HAMDULLAH EMİN PAŞA ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANTALYA AKEV ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ANTALYA BİLİM ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ARTVİN ÇORUH ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["AYDIN ADNAN MENDERES ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BALIKESİR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BANDIRMA ONYEDİ EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BİLECİK ŞEYH EDEBALİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BİNGÖL ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BİTLİS EREN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BOLU ABANT İZZET BAYSAL ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BURDUR MEHMET AKİF ERSOY ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BURSA TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BURSA ULUDAĞ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "FARUK SARAÇ TASARIM MESLEK YÜKSEKOKULU"], ["ÇANAKKALE ONSEKİZ MART ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ÇANKIRI KARATEKİN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["HİTİT ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["PAMUKKALE ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["DİCLE ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["TRAKYA ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["FIRAT ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ERZİNCAN BİNALİ YILDIRIM ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ATATÜRK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ERZURUM TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ANADOLU ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ESKİŞEHİR OSMANGAZİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ESKİŞEHİR TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["GAZİANTEP BİLİM VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "GAZİANTEP ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "HASAN KALYONCU ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SANKO ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["GİRESUN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["GÜMÜŞHANE ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["HAKKARİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["HATAY MUSTAFA KEMAL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSKENDERUN TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ISPARTA UYGULAMALI BİLİMLER ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SÜLEYMAN DEMİREL ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ÇAĞ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "MERSİN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TARSUS ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TOROS ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ACIBADEM MEHMET ALİ AYDINLAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ALTINBAŞ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ATAŞEHİR ADIGÜZEL MESLEK YÜKSEKOKULU", "AVRUPA MESLEK YÜKSEKOKULU", "BAHÇEŞEHİR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BEYKENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BEYKOZ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BEZM-İ ÂLEM VAKIF ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BİRUNİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "BOĞAZİÇİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "DOĞUŞ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "FATİH SULTAN MEHMET VAKIF ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "FENERBAHÇE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "GALATASARAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "HALİÇ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "IŞIK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İBN HALDUN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL AREL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL ATLAS ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL AYDIN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL AYVANSARAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL BİLGİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL BİLİM ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL ESENYURT ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL GEDİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL GELİŞİM ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL KENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL KÜLTÜR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL MEDENİYET ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL MEDİPOL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL OKAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL RUMELİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL SABAHATTİN ZAİM ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL ŞEHİR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL ŞİŞLİ MESLEK YÜKSEKOKULU", "İSTANBUL TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL TİCARET ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL ÜNİVERSİTESİ - CERRAHPAŞA", "İSTANBUL YENİ YÜZYIL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTANBUL 29 MAYIS ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İSTİNYE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İZMİR KAVRAM MESLEK YÜKSEKOKULU", "KADİR HAS ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KOÇ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "MALTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "MARMARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "MEF ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "MİMAR SİNAN GÜZEL SANATLAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "NİŞANTAŞI ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ÖZYEĞİN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "PİRİ REİS ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SABANCI ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SAĞLIK BİLİMLERİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SEMERKAND BİLİM VE MEDENİYET ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TÜRK-ALMAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TÜRKİYE ULUSLARARASI İSLAM, BİLİM VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TÜRK-JAPON BİLİM VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ÜSKÜDAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "YEDİTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "YILDIZ TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["DOKUZ EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "EGE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İZMİR BAKIRÇAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İZMİR DEMOKRASİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İZMİR EKONOMİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İZMİR KATİP ÇELEBİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İZMİR TINAZTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "İZMİR YÜKSEK TEKNOLOJİ ENSTİTÜSÜ", "YAŞAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KAFKAS ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KASTAMONU ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ABDULLAH GÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "ERCİYES ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KAYSERİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "NUH NACİ YAZGAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KIRKLARELİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KIRŞEHİR AHİ EVRAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["GEBZE TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KOCAELİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KONYA GIDA VE TARIM ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KONYA TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KTO KARATAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "NECMETTİN ERBAKAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SELÇUK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KÜTAHYA DUMLUPINAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KÜTAHYA SAĞLIK BİLİMLERİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["İNÖNÜ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "MALATYA TURGUT ÖZAL ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["MANİSA CELÂL BAYAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KAHRAMANMARAŞ İSTİKLAL ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KAHRAMANMARAŞ SÜTÇÜ İMAM ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["MARDİN ARTUKLU ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["MUĞLA SITKI KOÇMAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["MUŞ ALPARSLAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KAPADOKYA ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "NEVŞEHİR HACI BEKTAŞ VELİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["NİĞDE ÖMER HALİSDEMİR ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ORDU ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["RECEP TAYYİP ERDOĞAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SAMSUN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["SAKARYA UYGULAMALI BİLİMLER ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SAKARYA ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ONDOKUZ MAYIS ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["SİİRT ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["SİNOP ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["SİVAS BİLİM VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "SİVAS CUMHURİYET ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["TEKİRDAĞ NAMIK KEMAL ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["TOKAT GAZİOSMANPAŞA ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["AVRASYA ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "KARADENİZ TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "TRABZON ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["MUNZUR ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["HARRAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["UŞAK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["VAN YÜZÜNCÜ YIL ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["YOZGAT BOZOK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ZONGULDAK BÜLENT ECEVİT ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["AKSARAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BAYBURT ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KARAMANOĞLU MEHMETBEY ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KIRIKKALE ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BATMAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ŞIRNAK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["BARTIN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["ARDAHAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["IĞDIR ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["YALOVA ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KARABÜK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["KİLİS 7 ARALIK ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["OSMANİYE KORKUT ATA ÜNİVERSİTESİ"], ["DÜZCE ÜNİVERSİTESİ"]]
```

Can anyone help me about this problem? I have been working on it for 3 days but I can't fix it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am new at stackoverflow.I am sorry.I deleted empty spaces now.

Comment: You have two array properties, how can you be sure they are in sync? You were recommended in an earlier question to not use a [[String]] array but instead make use of the types you used for decoding and I am convinced you won’t have this issue if you follow that advice.

Comment: I don't know how can i do this.Can you help me whah should i use to fix this issue.

Comment: You didn’t mention what line it is that generates the errors.

Comment: CellForRowAt and numberOfRowsInSection methods generates error.Actually, when i printed uniList in uniViewModel closure, it printed correctly.However, if i print it in viewDidLoad method, out of uniViewModel closure, it generates error.You re right it doesn't being setted synchronously.

Comment: It does look to me like you are calling the exact same api function in both getProvinces and getUniversities which means you get the exact same data back twice so at least ditch one of those two functions and do whatever you want to do with your data in one place. The problem is clearly with your data and not with your table view code.

Comment: You re right bro.I made a lot of mistakes in this project.I learned a lot of things.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to reload tableview multiple times.

```
listViewModel.getProvinces { [weak self] provinces in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.uniViewModel.getUniversities {[weak self] unis in
           guard let self = self else { return }
           self.provincelist = provinces
           self.uniList = unis
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.uniList)
                print(self.provincelist)
            }
     } 
}
```

This may help with your crash. But, it is not the ideal solution. I don't know why you need to call same API twice to fetch province and universities.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I deleted one useless api call.Editted my api call function to returns both provinces and universities arrays.My problem solved.